# FormData envia datos null

Tags: jquery

Estoy tratando de hacer un update en mi base de datos, pero mi formulario  está enviando datos null. Mi formulario está obteniendo los datos de un datatable, sin embargo envia null.

Al hacer `console.log(form_data_update.get('#nombre_categoria_aux'));` Me resulta null.

Formulario modal de update
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

HTML del formulario modal

```html
<!-- VENTANA MODAL DE DATOS UPDATE-->
<div class="modal fade bd-example-modal-lg" id="categorias_modal_update" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="staticBackdropLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg modal-dialog-centered">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="staticBackdropLabel">Actualizar categoria</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">        
        <form id="categoria_form_update" name="categoria_form_update" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <label for="nombre_categoria_aux">Nombre de la categoria</label>
                <input id="nombre_categoria_aux" name="nombre_categoria" class="form-control" type="text" maxlength="45" required>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <label for="descripcion_categoria_aux">Descripción de la categoria</label>
                <textarea id="descripcion_categoria_aux" name="descripcion_categoria" class="form-control" type="text" maxlength="100" required></textarea>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <label for="estado_categoria_aux">Estado de la categoria</label>
                <select  id="estado_categoria_aux" name="estado_categoria"  class="custom-select" required>
                    <option value="0">Activado</option>
                    <option value="1">Desactivado</option>
                </select>                
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <label for="imagen_categoria_aux">Imagen de la categoria</label>
                <input id="imagen_categoria_aux" name="imagen_categoria" class="form-control" type="file" accept="image/jpg,image/png,image/jpeg" required>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">                
                <button id="actualizar_btn" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Guardar</button>
            </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Codigo formulario modal JQuery
Envio mis datos del datatable al modal

```html
/* ABRIR VENTANA MODAL PARA ACTUALIZAR*/
$(document).on('click','.btn-editar', function(){            
    fila = $(this).closest('tr');
    id_cat = parseInt(fila.find('td:eq(0)').text());      
    nombre_cat = fila.find('td:eq(1)').text();
    desc_cat = fila.find('td:eq(2)').text();
    estado_cat = fila.find('td:eq(3)').text() == 'Activado' ? 0:1; 

    /*ENVIO LOS DATOS DE LA TABLA A LOS CAMPOS DEL FORMULARIO*/
    $('#categorias_modal_update #nombre_categoria_aux').val(nombre_cat);
    $('#categorias_modal_update #descripcion_categoria_aux').val(desc_cat);
    $('#categorias_modal_update #estado_categoria_aux').val(estado_cat);  
    $('#categorias_modal_update #imagen_categoria_aux').prop('required',false);       
    $('#categorias_modal_update').modal('show');       
});
```

Codigo para enviar datos del formulario por AJAX

```html
/* ENVIAR DATOS PARA ACTUALIZAR*/
$('#categoria_form_update').submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();          
    form_data_update = new FormData(document.getElementById('categoria_form_update'));    
    console.log(form_data_update.get('#nombre_categoria_aux'));
    $.ajax({
        url:'../../services/CRUD/update_categoria.php',
        method:'POST',
        dataType:'json',
        contentType: false,
        data: form_data_insert,
        processData: false,
        cache: false,
        success: (response) => {
            console.log(response.status);
            if(response.status=='ACTUALIZADO'){
                Swal.fire({                   
                    icon: 'success',
                    title: 'Categoria actualizada',
                    showConfirmButton: false,
                    timer: 1500
                });                
                tabla_categorias.ajax.reload(null,false);   
            }else{
                Swal.fire({                   
                    icon: 'error',
                    title: 'Error al actualizar',
                    showConfirmButton: false,
                    timer: 1500
                }); 
            }

        }
    });
    $('#categorias_modal_update').modal('hide');
});
```

Comment: Hola, porque en el ajax estas mandando  form_data_insert no es form_data_update?

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, ya lo he resuelto.